# UWP Cannot select other song when backgroundaudiotask is running C#

Tags: c#, winrt-xaml, uwp

So my app has some pages. 4 pages are playing songs and the others are some other stuff:

1. Library page(I selected songs and added them to the app, users can play them)
2. Playlist selection page(User created a playlist. It will be displayed here)
3. Selected playlist page(User selected a playlist, can add/play songs)

I get an error with backgroundaudiotask when i switch from the library page to selected playlist page and i select a song. I already tried to update the playbacklist to the selected playlist. Already tried shutting down the backgroundmediaplayer but nothing works! It always throws an exception or doesn't play! 
Does anybody knows how to play a new song when switching from the library page?

If anybody could help that'd be awesome!

-Christos K

Comment: What exception is thrown? Please show us some code that could give us a hint about where the problem is.

Comment: @Herdo i will when i get home.

Comment: @Herdo Do you have skype? Something so we can talk or on stackoverflow chat?